# HTTP Error 405 when Browsing to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, http

I have my app that is creating an XML File with XMLTextWriter class in ASP .Net C#.  I create a nicely formed xml file, then spit out a link for the user.  When I click on the link, I recieve an error saying that Page cannot be displayed:

> "HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed."

However, at this point I place my cursor in the adress bar of the browser, and hit enter and Viola!, my nice xml file is displayed.

1. Why does it take an enter, in order to make my browser behave.
2. What can I do to to correct this so that when we click on the link the xml file displays without needing the extra enter in the browser address bar?

I went into my web server already and added the XML mime type to the registered mim types at the web server level.

I am wondering what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are generating the link to XML file? Also the generated `<a href/>` element?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems there is something wrong with the link you are using.
View the source from your browser and verify that the  tag is pointing to the correct location.  Also, make sure it is only pointing to the one document and not doing anything else like calling javascript functions or posting back.

Comment: I verified that the link isn't calling any javascript and I know for sure that it is pointing to the correct location as, when I hit enter on the browser bar, it displays perfectly.

Comment: @user1040113 interesting.  If you want to know exactly why it happens I would suggest Wireshark or to check the IIS logs.  Otherwise I would suggest changing the hyperlink to a repose.redirect or changing the file type to .txt.